# CSS - Nesting grid within grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and at one place I have nested fluid-grid in parent fluid-grid. It seems to work, but my question is - whether this is considered bad practice and are there any side effects of doing so?

Comment: You might run into problems with doubling of column gutters though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the grids are properly nested then there should be no problem. Grids were made to be flexible and is not considered bad practice to step out of the norm with the design, specially with fluid grids that should (by their nature) adapt to their container.